# GATE Embedded sample Example NoClassFound Error

Tags: java, gate

I am new to GATE Embedded , i tried simple example and getting NoClassDefFoundError.
First i will explain what i tried

1. Donwload and Extract Gate 7.0 in **D:\project\gate-7.0**
2. Netbean create new project --> added library gate.jar and lib folder
3. Tried to execute simple java code

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws GateException, IOException 
 {
  // initialise the GATE library
  Out.prln("Initialising GATE...");
  Gate.init();
  Out.prln("...GATE initialised");
}
```

Run time getting error

```
Initialising GATE...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at gate.Gate.<clinit>(Gate.java:83)
        at gatedemo.StandaloneDemo.main(StandaloneDemo.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
```

I think error is related to classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Netbean create new project --> added library gate.jar and lib folder

You need your application's classpath to contain all of the JAR files that are inside the `lib` folder, not the folder itself.

Note that once you fix this you will probably get a warning saying GATE "could not initialize Log4J" - to avoid this either add GATE's `bin` directory to your application's classpath as well, [create your own `log4j.properties`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29) in your project's top level src directory, or add

```
org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

at the top of your `main` method.

P.S. I also recommend you use a more recent GATE (7.1 or a current snapshot) unless you have a specific reason why you must use an old release.